# Overwrite {} in python

Tags: python, dictionary, overwrite

I want to make a dict int which you can access like that:

```
>>> my_dict["property'] = 3
>>> my_dict.property
3
```

So I've made this one:

```
class DictAsMember(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
```

This works fine, but if you have nested dicts it doesn't work, e.g:

```
my_dict = DictAsMember()
my_dict["property"] = {'sub': 1}
```

I can access to my_dict.property but logically I can't do my_dict.property.sub because property is a default dict, so what i want to do it's overwrite the default dict, so you can use {}.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One workaround to the problem is wrapping default dictionaries using `DictAsMember` before returning them in the `__getattr__` method:

```
class DictAsMember(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        value = self[name]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = DictAsMember(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            value = [DictAsMember(element)
                     if isinstance(element, dict)
                     else element
                     for element in value]

        return value

my_dict = DictAsMember()
my_dict["property"] = {'sub': 1}
print my_dict.property.sub    # 1 will be printed

my_dict = DictAsMember()
my_dict["property"] = [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]
print my_dict.property[1].name    # 2 will be printed
```

Comment: The only problem that i find with that is if you have an array with dicts, e.g:
    my_dict["properties"] = [{'name': 1}, {'name':2}]
Yo can modify the workaround so it takes into account the arrays, that's why i was looking for a way to overwrite the default dict

Comment: @Félix Things will get a little more complex, but dictionaries inside lists can still be wrapped. I've updated my answer to show an example using dictionaries inside a list.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing your own class to implement the `my_dict.property` notation (this is called object notation) you could instead use named tuples. Named tuple can be referenced using object like variable deferencing or the standard tuple syntax. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

> The [named tuple] is used to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible
>   by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable.

As an example of their use:

```
from collections import *

my_structure = namedtuple('my_structure', ['name', 'property'])
my_property  = namedtuple('my_property', ['sub'])

s = my_structure('fred', my_property(1))

s # my_structure(name='fred', property=my_property(sub=1)) will be printed

s.name # 'fred' will be printed

s.property # my_property(sub=1) will be printed

s.property.sub # 1 will be printed
```

See also the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) for a nice summary of named tuples.