# Getting an element from tuple of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tuple value by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731231/tuple-value-by-key)

How do i find the country name by having its code,

```
COUNTRIES = (
   ('AF', _(u'Afghanistan')),
   ('AX', _(u'\xc5land Islands')),
   ('AL', _(u'Albania')),
   ('DZ', _(u'Algeria')),
   ('AS', _(u'American Samoa')),
   ('AD', _(u'Andorra')),
   ('AO', _(u'Angola')),
   ('AI', _(u'Anguilla'))
)
```

I have code `AS`, find its name without using forloop on  `COUNTRIES` tuple?

Comment: i have to use tuples, i know its easy in dict.

Comment: @Sergey: Django uses assoc lists in some places.

Comment: @Ahsan: You have to either convert it to a dict before trying to fetch the key, or loop until you find the key. There's no other way.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
countries_dict = dict(COUNTRIES)  # Conversion to a dictionary mapping
print countries_dict['AS']
```

This simply creates a mapping between country abbreviations and country names.  Accessing the mapping is very fast: this is probably the fastest method if you do multiple lookups, as Python's dictionary lookup is very efficient.

Comment: Do you know if the conversion + lookup is faster than looping through the tuples for a match?

Comment: @daramarak: for a single lookup creating a dictionary should be slower. see my downvoted answer.. :/

Comment: @yi_H: interesting point raised! But the time complexity for a **for loop** is O(n), and accessing a tuple/dictionary is O(1). Are you talking about the time consumed for type casting? Please specify your logic.

Comment: @mangobug: creating the dictionary is O(n) and you have to allocate space and copy the entries... for that, you obviously have to loop through the tuple. now compare this with a simple loop which finds the appropriate entry.

Comment: point taken!! +1 to your answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
COUNTRIES = (
   ('AF', (u'Afghanistan')),
   ('AX', (u'\xc5land Islands')),
   ('AL', (u'Albania')),
   ('DZ', (u'Algeria')),
   ('AS', (u'American Samoa')),
   ('AD', (u'Andorra')),
   ('AO', (u'Angola')),
   ('AI', (u'Anguilla'))
)

print (country for (code, country) in COUNTRIES if code=='AD').next()
#>>> Andorra

print next((country for (code, country) in COUNTRIES if code=='AD'), None)
#Andorra
print next((country for (code, country) in COUNTRIES if code=='Blah'), None)
#None

# If you want to do multiple lookups, the best is to make a dict:
d = dict(COUNTRIES)
print d['AD']
#>>> Andorra
```

Comment: This is an already stated answer by many. Why repeat yourself?

Comment: I have not seen example with generator in other examples, this is nice. +1

Comment: The generator version could be made shorter by doing `next(country for code,country in COUNTRIES if code=='AD')`. The builtin `next(a) -> a.next()`. (Admittedly, in a micro-benchmark the builtin `next` will perform worse because of this, but it's a fun fact, anyway.) There is actually one way in which using the builtin `next` is better: its `default` argument. e.g. `next((country for code,country in COUNTRIES if code=='AD'), None)` will return `None` if there is no language match.

Comment: +1 for the efficient generator. Note that `next(…)` is officially recommended over your `….next()`, though, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Either

```
[x[1] for x in COUNTRIES if x[0] == 'AS'][0]
```

or

```
filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'AS', COUNTRIES)[0][1]
```

but these are still "loops".

Comment: No downvote, but both these solutions are inefficient: all the countries are re-read for each lookup, even if the 'AS' country is found at the beginning of the list of countries.

Comment: You mean it's inefficient *if* there are multiple lookups.

Comment: These methods are actually *always* inefficient: even if the 'AS' country is found right at the beginning of the COUNTRIES list, the rest of the list is unnecessarily read anyway.  robert king's answer shows an efficient way to do something similar.

Comment: @EOL: yepp, `(..).next()` would be better..