# get tuple list element by string name in python

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, tuples

I have the following tuple list:  It is for choice fields in a django model.

```
ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0,'choice1'),
    (1,'choice2'),
)
```

I want to get the choices by their string name like:

```
entity_type_index = ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES['choice1']
```

I get the error:

> tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tuple value by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731231/tuple-value-by-key)

Comment: You wanted to access the value by its other value...

Comment: As said, tuples elements must be accessed by their position, so a number.
You may want to try a dictionary instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dictionary:

```
ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
(0,'choice1'),
(1,'choice2'),
)

ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = dict([i[::-1] for i in ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES])

entity_type_index = ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES['choice1']
```

Output:

```
0
```

If you cannot use a dictionary:

```
new_choice = [i[0] for i in ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES if i[1] == 'choice1']

print new_choice[0]
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? I see this completely fine.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: I'm just guessing: The choice field in a django model has to be a tuple, not a dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the tuple. Tuple objects can only be accessed by indexes, not elements (as dictionaries)

```
ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0,'choice1'),
    (1,'choice2'),
)

choice = 0

for i in ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES:
 if i[1] == "choice1":
  choice = i[0]
```

If you now print it:

```
print(choice)  # Output: 0
```

And you can now use it with `choice`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the choice using `ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES.index('choice1')`

Then you can use the number it gives to access it, by using:

```
 ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES[ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES.index('choice1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Type of `ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES` is `tuple`, but you use it as `dict`.

you can write method for iterate over tuple and find key:

```
get_entity_type_index(k):
    for index, key in ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES:
         if key == k: return index
```

But this way is not the best practice.

---

Base on @Ajax1234 answer:

```
ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
   (0,'choice1'),
   (1,'choice2'),
)

ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES_INDEX = {value: key for key, value in ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES} 

print(ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES_INDEX['choice2']) # output: 1
```