# Python look up key in tuple

Tags: python

I have a question related [to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731231/tuple-value-by-key) about looking up key values in a dictionary.

The dictionary called `vavs` how do I look up if a name equals one of the keys?

```
# format : key = name, v = (address, device_identifier) tuple
vavs = {'vav1_01': ('1701:1', 160101),
        'vav1_02': ('1701:2', 160102),
        'vav1_03': ('1701:3', 160103),
        'vav1_04': ('1701:4', 160104),
        'vav1_05': ('1701:5', 160105),
        'vav1_06': ('1701:6', 160106),
        'vav1_07': ('1701:7', 160107),
        'vav1_08': ('1701:8', 160108),
        'vav1_09': ('1701:9', 160109),
        'vav1_10': ('1701:10', 160110),
        'vav1_11': ('1701:11', 160111),
        'vav1_12': ('1701:12', 160112),
        'vav2_01': ('1701:13', 160113),
        'vav2_02': ('1701:14', 160114),
        'vav2_03': ('1701:15', 160115),
        'vav2_04': ('1701:16', 160116),
        'vav2_05': ('1701:17', 160117),
        'vav2_06': ('1701:18', 160118),
        'vav2_07': ('1701:19', 160119),
        'vav2_08': ('1701:20', 160120),
        'vav2_09': ('1701:21', 160121),
        'vav2_10': ('1701:22', 160122),
        'vav2_11': ('1701:23', 160123),
        'vav2_12': ('1701:24', 160124),
       }

#dict(TUPLE)[key]
d = dict(vavs)

print(d['vav2_12'])

for vav in vavs.items:
    if vav == ['vav2_12']:
        print(d['vav2_12'])
```

This doesnt work, get a

```
>>> 
========== RESTART: C:\Users\benb\Desktop\text_parse\vavNumTest.py ==========
('1701:24', 160124)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benb\Desktop\text_parse\vavNumTest.py", line 37, in <module>
    for vav in vavs.items:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: `is vavs.items()` with parenthesis at the end

Comment: Ah thanks i did forget the `()` but when I run the code again its like the if statement doesnt pickup `if vav == ['vav2_12']:`

Comment: any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You need to do `vav[0] = 'vav2_12'`, that is check if the key is equals to vav2_12.

Comment: Thanks that worked... The link for the duplicate post/answer I didnt find anything useful there... If post an answer Ill hit the green check