# When and why should I use a namedtuple instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python

The standard library `namedtuple` class looks to me like a way to make tuples more like dictionaries. How do `namedtuple`s compare to `dict`s? When should we use them? Do they work with non-hashable types?

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: ^-- agreed:  [2970608](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) has named tuple FAQs and this one asks for comparison to dict.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

In `dict`s, only the keys have to be hashable, not the values. `namedtuple`s don't have keys, so hashability isn't an issue.

However, they have a more stringent restriction -- their key-equivalents, "field names", have to be strings.

Basically, if you were going to create a bunch of instances of a class like:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, name, date, foo, bar):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

mycontainer = Container(name, date, foo, bar)
```

and **not change the attributes after you set them in `__init__`,** you could instead use

```
Container = namedtuple('Container', ['name', 'date', 'foo', 'bar'])

mycontainer = Container(name, date, foo, bar)
```

as a replacement.

Of course, you could create a bunch of `dict`s where you used the same keys in each one, but assuming you will have only valid Python identifiers as keys and don't need mutability,

```
mynamedtuple.fieldname
```

is prettier than

```
mydict['fieldname']
```

and

```
mynamedtuple = MyNamedTuple(firstvalue, secondvalue)
```

is prettier than

```
mydict = {'fieldname': firstvalue, 'secondfield': secondvalue}
```

Finally, `namedtuple`s are ordered, unlike regular `dict`s, so you get the items in the order you defined the fields, unlike a `dict`.

Comment: Also, quoting Raymondh: "Instances of named tuples use no more space than regular tuples. The field name properties are stored in the namedtuple class." https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/524660721968107521

Comment: One more thing to note is that the named tuple can also be initialized as `mynamedtuple = MyNamedTuple(fieldname=firstvalue, secondfield=secondvalue)`

Comment: You can make the instantiatiation even prettier/simpler with `Container = namedtuple('Container', 'name date foo bar')`

Comment: If you need more flexibility, [attrs](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/why.html#namedtuples) is an interesting alternative to namedtuple.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.7 or CPython 3.6 `dicts` are [insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6).

Comment: @Boris Good info, but still different from field definition ordering and in many situations just as unknown as random ordering.

Comment: NamedTuples take advantage of attribute autocompletion provided by many IDEs, since they use attribute access rather than key lookup. No more checking `parse_x_data()` source code for a dict signature.

Answer (score 49):

Tuples are immutable, whether named or not. `namedtuple` only makes the access more convenient, by using names instead of indices. You can only use valid identifiers for `namedtuple`, it doesn't perform any hashing — it generates a new type instead.