# Why do namedtuples use less memory than dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm asking this because I found it surprising -- I thought a `namedtuple` would have more overhead.

(The background is I was caching a large Django query in memory and found Django objects to be 100x the size of `.values()`.  I then wondered what overhead `namedtuple` versions of the objects would be, allowing me to still use `.` access to the items as attributes.  Smaller was not what I expected.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

from pympler.asizeof import asizeof                                             
from collections import namedtuple                                              

import random                                                                   
import string                                                                   

QTY = 100000                                                                    


class Foz(object):                                                              
    pass                                                                        

dicts = [{'foo': random.randint(0, 10000),                                      
          'bar': ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(32)]),
          'baz': random.randrange(10000),                                       
          'faz': random.choice([True, False]),                                  
          'foz': Foz()} for _ in range(QTY)]                                    

print "%d dicts: %d" % (len(dicts), asizeof(dicts))                             

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921240/pythonic-way-to-convert-dictionary-to-namedtuple-or-another-hashable-dict-like

MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', sorted(dicts[0]))                               

tuples = [MyTuple(**d) for d in dicts]                                          

print "%d namedtuples: %d" % (len(tuples), asizeof(tuples))                     

print "Ratio: %.01f" % (float(asizeof(tuples)) / float(asizeof(dicts)))
```

Running,

```
$ ./foo.py    
100000 dicts: 75107672
100000 namedtuples: 56707472
Ratio: 0.8
```

A single tuple is even less, perhaps due to the overhead of `list`:

```
$ ./foo.py    
1 dicts: 1072
1 namedtuples: 688
Ratio: 0.6
```

Is it the overhead of the hashtable array?  But wouldn't a `namedtuple` also need a hashtable of the attributes?  Is `pympler` not being accurate?

Comment: What operations do each support?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'd expect private code (even if counted by `asizeof`) to be averaged out over large numbers of items.

Comment: [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Comment: No, a `namedtuple` does not need a hashtable. Its is a tuple. It is *specifically for saving memory*. That is it's use-case, and to make working with tuples more readable / self-documenting.

Answer (score 9):

The basic answer is simply "yes": A normal object has an internal dictionary to store the instance's attributes:

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
print(f.__dict__)
# {}
```

It needs to be a dict because in Python you are allowed to assign new attributes on an instance that were not defined by the class:

```
f.a = 1
print(f.__dict__)
# {'a': 1}
```

Using a dict allows fast attribute lookups, but there is memory overhead due to the data structure itself. Also, because different instances of `Foo` may have different attributes defined on them, every single instance might need its own dict:

```
g = Foo()
print(g.__dict__)
# {}
print(f.__dict_ == g.__dict__)
# False
```

A `namedtuple` does not allow adding attributes at runtime. A specific instance of `namedtuple` can, therefore, store all of its attributes in a single instance being shared by all instances.

Given a `namedtuple` and an instance:

```
Foo = collections.namedtuple("Foo", 'a,b')
f = Foo(1,2)
```

The `namedtuple`-constructor [generates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12083284c54be25abadd85781d36b63731dc1f0c/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L458) a [descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798882/2722968) for each field and stores it in the class; here is where the translation between named attribute and tuple index is stored. When you access attribute `a` on instance `f`, the attribute access is routed through this descriptor:

```
type(Foo.a)
#<class 'property'>
```

Comment: Where are the keys stored in a `namedtuple` for accessing attributes by name?  i.e., `.foo`

Comment: In the class, not the instance

Comment: Updated the answer to make clear that the memory savings come from sharing the attribute dictionary in the class

Comment: @user2722968 I think showing some of this would improve your already great answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916853/how-named-tuples-are-implemented-internally-in-python

Comment: @user2722968 But yes!  The name mapping is done in the class as properties!

Answer (score 4):

> But wouldn't a namedtuple also need a hashtable of the attributes?

Nope. A namedtuple's instance layout is exactly the same as a regular tuple. The mapping from tuple entries to attributes is provided by generated [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors), which are a mechanism Python provides for controlling attribute resolution. The descriptors are stored in the generated namedtuple type, so they're a per-type cost, not per-instance. Currently, the descriptors are [`property` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), as you can see in the [current implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L455), but that's subject to change (especially if any of this gets rewritten in C).

A namedtuple gets to be way more memory-efficient than a dict because as far as memory layout goes, it's just a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It would stand to reason that a named tuple only needs its mapping once for all instances (name --> index). The hashing table is probably located in some centrally located meta-data (namespace), not in the object itself so it is not counted in the memory allocation of each instance.