# How to iterate through a dictionary and print (output) the individual values?

Tags: python, loops

I have an assignment to take in user input to create a grocery list of items, and to eventually output this information along with a grand total onto a receipt.

Example: The user inputs the following grocery items:
`{'name':'milk', 'number': 1, 'price': 2.00}, {'name':'eggs', 'number':2, 'price': 3.99}, {'name': 'onions', 'number': 4, 'price':0.79}`.

Then I would want my ouput to be:

```
1 milk @ $2.99 ea $2.99
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $14.13
```

**Instead** my ouput is:

```
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $9.48
```

Here is the code I am using. I have a strong feeling my for loop is to blame (they have been the hardest thing to master for me), but I'm not sure why it is only printing the last entry over and over.

```
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = []

stop = 'go'

while stop != 'q' :
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")

    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = int(quantity)
    grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

print("Would you like to enter another item?")
stop = input("Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")

grand_total = []

for grocery_item in grocery_history:

    item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
    grand_total.append(item_total)
    print(grocery_item['number'], end=' ')
    print(grocery_item['name'],end=' ')
    print('@', end=' ')
    print('$%.2f' % (grocery_item['price']), end=' ')
    print('ea', end=' ')
    print('$%.2f' % (item_total))
    item_total = 0

sum = sum(grand_total)
print('Grand total: $%.2f' % (sum))
```

Comment: post the code on how are you populating `grocery_history`

Comment: Did you by any chance do `[{}] * 3`?

Comment: Here we go. Move `grocery_item = {}` into the loop, or else you append the _same_ dictionary to the list _each time_. So, if you modify one, you modify them all _just the same_.

Comment: I apologize again - just included all of my previous code as well!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thank you so much! It's always the (seemingly) simplest things!!

Comment: i think you'd be better off going with a list of namedtuples, as your keys are redundant across all dictionaries.  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872255/when-and-why-should-i-use-a-namedtuple-instead-of-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting:

```
s = [{'name':'milk', 'number': 1, 'price': 2.00}, {'name':'eggs', 'number':2, 'price': 3.99}, {'name': 'onions', 'number': 4, 'price':0.79}]
for val in s:
   print("{number} {name} @ ${price} ea ${final}".format(**{**val, **{'final':val['number']*val['price']}}))
print('Grand Total: $'+str(sum(val['price']*val['number'] for val in s)))
```

Output:

```
1 milk @ $2.0 ea $2.0
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand Total: $13.14
```

Edit: regarding your code you added for `grocery_item` initialization, `grocery_item` is always being updated at each iteration. Instead, declare `grocery_item` in the scope of the while loop:

```
while stop != 'q':
   grocery_item = {}
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in that case we must wait until the OP clarifies what the contents of `grocery_history` are.

Comment: Exactly! Ideally, one would first ask for this clarification and _then_ write the answer. ;-) I have my doubts that your answer as it stands is going to help OP (hint: see my comment)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm sorry about that! Fixing that now to include all of my code. I was trying to keep it as brief as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working fine ,I tested it in my PC. Check this code

```
grocery_history = [{'name':'milk', 'number': 1, 'price': 2.00}, {'name':'eggs', 'number':2, 'price': 3.99}, {'name': 'onions', 'number': 4, 'price':0.79}]
grand_total = []

for grocery_item in grocery_history:

    item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
    grand_total.append(item_total)
    print(grocery_item['number'], end=' ')
    print(grocery_item['name'],end=' ')
    print('@', end=' ')
    print('$%.2f' % (grocery_item['price']), end=' ')
    print('ea', end=' ')
    print('$%.2f' % (item_total))
    item_total = 0

sum = sum(grand_total)
print('Grand total: $%.2f' % (sum))
```

Here is the result:

```
"C:\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe" F:/MyJobs/StackOverflow/StackOverflow.py
1 milk @ $2.00 ea $2.00
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $13.14

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You should check the way , how "grocery_history" is assigned.

Comment: If it works for you, and if the only thing you did differently from the question is the way you initialised you `grocery_history`, then it follows that the issue lies with the initialisation of that data structure. Writing an answer proclaiming that OP's code works, rather than getting to the root cause, isn't helping OP.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code hope it helps: [Python3.6]

```
items = [{'name':'milk', 'number': 1, 'price': 2.00}, {'name':'eggs', 'number':2, 'price': 3.99}, {'name': 'onions', 'number': 4, 'price':0.79}]
grand_total = 0.0
for item in items:
    item_total = item['price'] * item['number']
    grand_total += item_total
    print('{number} {name} @ ${price} ea $'.format(**item) + '{0}'.format(item_total))
print('Grand total: ${0}'.format(grand_total))
```

Comment: No, in all probability does not help. The issue is 99% the manner in which OP has created their data. I don't know what you're doing here, but I don't think it'll do anything different for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your `grocery_history` has 3 elements, for which all 3 of them are all referring to same `grocery_item`

You keep reusing the same instance of dict as `grocery_item`, and put the **same instance** into the `grocery_history` multiple times.

A quick fix is

```
while stop != 'q' :
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")

    grocery_item = {}   # a new dict
    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = int(quantity)
    grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)
    # or simply do 
    # grocery_item = { "name" : item_name, "number": int(quantity)... }

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
```