# Relevance of typename in namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, typename, namedtuple

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('whatsmypurpose',['x','y'])
p = Point(11,22)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
whatsmypurpose(x=11,y=22)
```

What's the relevance/use of `'whatsmypurpose'`?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python   "It becames more readable" - so, readability it is. And more: "you should use named tuples instead of tuples anywhere you think object notation will make your code more pythonic and more easily readable."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of class typenames in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482512/use-of-class-typenames-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`namedtuple()` is a factory function for `tuple` subclasses. Here, `'whatsmypurpose'`is the type name. When you create a named tuple, a class with this name (`whatsmypurpose`) gets created internally.

You can notice this by using the verbose argument like:

```
Point=namedtuple('whatsmypurpose',['x','y'], verbose=True)
```

Also you can try `type(p)` to verify this.

Comment: 3.3 also adds the attribute `_source`, in case you want to `print` or `exec` the definition.

Comment: I've don't seem to be able to access the class.  ie, whatsmypurpose() above is not defined.   Is the class actually defined somewhere or is typename only for display purposes?

Comment: @Gadi Point is the reference (variable) to the class called 'whatsmypurpose' in the example above. So in general the class name (`Point.__name__`) is for display purposes (try `print(Point(1, 2))`).

Comment: I think an important point to make here is that _**Python cannot surmise what your new class's name should be by looking at the name of the variable you're assigning the class object to**_. The variable doesn't't exist yet! Thus, Python needs you to explicitly tell it what name to assign the new class object.

Comment: @ChristianDean Conceivably the redundancy could removed from *other end* by eliminating the need to explicitly assign `namedtuple(...)` to a variable.  For example, I could imagine something like `register_namedtuple('name', ..., locals())` that automatically adds `name` to `locals()`.

Comment: True @jamesdlin, although I'm not sure how I'd feel about a function hacking into local variables like that behind the scene. [Explict is better than implicit, no?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 9):

`'whatsmypurpose'` gives the new subclass its type name.  From the docs:

> collections.namedtuple(***typename***, field_names, verbose=False,rename=False)
> Returns a new tuple subclass named ***typename***.

Here is an example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['a', 'b'])
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'type'>
>>> a = Foo(a = 1, b = 2)
>>> a
Foo(a=1, b=2)
>>> Foo = namedtuple('whatsmypurpose', ['a', 'b'])
>>> a = Foo(a = 1, b = 2)
>>> a
whatsmypurpose(a=1, b=2)
>>>
```

---

Set the `verbose` parameter to `True` and you can see the complete `whatsmypurpose` class definition.

```
>>> Foo = namedtuple('whatsmypurpose', ['a', 'b'], verbose=True)
from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

class whatsmypurpose(tuple):
    'whatsmypurpose(a, b)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('a', 'b')

    def __new__(_cls, a, b):
        'Create new instance of whatsmypurpose(a, b)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (a, b))

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new whatsmypurpose object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != 2:
            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
        return result

    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new whatsmypurpose object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('a', 'b'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % list(kwds))
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(a=%r, b=%r)' % self

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self)

    a = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')

    b = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
class MyClass(tuple):
   pass
```

This creates a *type*, which is a tuple subclass, and it has a name `MyClass.__name__ == "MyClass"`.  `namedtuple` is a *type factory*, it also creates tuple subclasses, but in this functional API you have to pass the name explicitly.

When you assign the returned type to a different name:

```
Point = namedtuple('whatsmypurpose',['x','y'])
```

It is similar to doing this:

```
class whatsmypurpose(tuple):
    ... # extra stuff here to setup slots, field names, etc

Point = whatsmypurpose
del whatsmypurpose
```

In both cases you are just aliasing a different name to the type.

Usually you would assign to the same name as used for the type name. If you are bothered that repeating the same string is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), then you can use the declarative API in [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead of that functional API in `collections`. <sub>Then you can be bothered by needing to annotate types, instead.</sub>