# Why can I not read the 'typename' after creating a namedtuple object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

This query is further with reference to [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762236/relevance-of-typename-in-namedtuple)

So, I am trying to execute the following code :

```
from collections import *

tp = namedtuple('emp', 'eid enames mob')
print(tp)
print(emp)
```

I can execute `print(tp)` and the output generated is `<class '__main__.emp'>`.

But when I try to execute `print(emp)`, It generates the following exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(emp)
NameError: name 'emp' is not defined
```

What is the reason. The class `emp` is created. But I can not figure out how to access it directly. Or can I not ?

So basically, I can create instance of `tp` as `tp()` but not instances of `emp` in the same way. Why?

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1:*** Just repeat the type name when assigning to the returned type

```
tp = emp = namedtuple('emp', 'eid enames mob')
```

***Option 2***: Use a declarative style instead of the functional APIs

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class emp(NamedTuple):
    eid: str
    enames: str
    mob: str
```

Comment: I want to know what is the purpose of `emp` if I cannot use it. I have edited the question to reflect the same.

Comment: It is set as the name of the type. Check tp.__name__

Comment: you are right, `tp.__name__` does display `emp`. In fact if I create an object of `tp`, the `type(myobj)` shows type as `emp`. But I cannot use `emp` to create an object. Why is it so?

Comment: Because the name emp is unbound in your scope. You assigned the returned type to a different name.