# Edited : how to declare array of struct in Python

Tags: python, c, arrays, struct

### EDITED ALL

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

FDResult = namedtuple('FDResult', ['DeviceID', 'PageNum'])
#bla = [FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951113', PageNum=[1,2,3,4]),
 #FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951114', PageNum=[17,28,63,64]),
 #FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951115', PageNum=[2,3,4,5])]

bla = [FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951115', PageNum=[1])] #how to declare bla as FDResult array and blank data inside,Length of bla should equal 0
bla.append(FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951112', PageNum=[2])) 
print(len(bla))

bla[0].PageNum.append(16)
```

how to declare array of struct in Python?
FDResult array and blank data inside,Length of bla should equal 0

## ANSWER

```
FDResult = namedtuple('FDResult', ['DeviceID', 'PageNum'])
#bla = [FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951113', PageNum=[1,2,3,4]),
 #FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951114', PageNum=[17,28,63,64]),
 #FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951115', PageNum=[2,3,4,5])]
NodeList = []

Node = FDResult(DeviceID='NR0951113', PageNum=[1,2,3,4])
NodeList.append(Node)
print(len(NodeList))
NodeList[0].PageNum.append(16)
```

Comment: @Volatility how to create namedtuple array?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2970722/1907098)

Comment: @Volatility Question Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create namedtuple array like this.

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyStruct = namedtuple('MyStruct', 'Mark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd')

NodeList = []
Node = MyStruct(None, '', '', '', '',  -1, 0)
for id in range(4):
     NodeList.append(Node)
```

Answer (score 0):

If length of `bla` should be zero, just create an empty list:

```
bla = []
```

A Python list can contain objects of any type. If `bla` is only supposed to hold `FDResult` instances, it is your responsibility as programmer not to put anything else there.