# Alternative to bidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, class

I need a array of `n` elements, in which each element has 2 attributes.

```
A.element[0].name="qwe"
A.element[0].age=23
A.element[1].name="www"
A.element[1].age=24
...
A.element[n].name="e"
A.element[n].age=25
```

Is there another form which doesn't involve designing a class?

Answer (score 4):

There is [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple).

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Element = namedtuple('Element', 'name age')
>>> A.element[0] = Element('qwe', 23)
>>> print A.element[0].name
qwe
>>> print A.element[0].age
23
```

However these are tuples, not lists, and so they can't be changed. Also, these are still essentially classes, but you just don't define them with the `class` keyword. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970722/1907098) for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of dictionaries.

Something like this:

```
A = [
    {'name': 'qwe', 'age': 23},
    {'name': 'www', 'age': 24}
]
```

You can simplify inserting by doing something like this:

```
A = []

def addPerson(name, age):
    global A
    A.append({'name': name, 'age': age})
```

Or just make the dictionaries into arrays, so you do not have to specify 'name' and 'age' in every line. It might be easier writing a class representing a person (or whatever it is).

Comment: I liked, but remove the global!

Answer (score 1):

If you use numpy, you can also use structure array:

```
In [66]: struct = np.dtype([("name", np.object), ("age", np.int)])
a = np.array([("abc", 12), ("def", 20), ("xyz", 50)], dtype=struct)
a[0]
Out[66]: ('abc', 12)

In [67]: a[0]["name"]
Out[67]: 'abc'

In [68]: a["name"]
Out[68]: array([abc, def, xyz], dtype=object)

In [69]: a["age"]
Out[69]: array([12, 20, 50])

In [72]: a["age"][2]
Out[72]: 50
```