# pydoc supported python metadata such as __version__ = '0.1'

Tags: python, pydoc

I'm not even really sure what these things are officially called, though, Python has metadata, usually at the top of the module files such as `__version__ = '0.1'`.

How can I find a list of all of the ones supported by PyDoc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any top-level private globals following a particular naming convention will be included under the `Data` section generated by **Pydoc**:

- All normal global variables are displayed there – you can see this simply by running **pydoc** on a module with some global variables that is otherwise empty.
- "Special" names are displayed (but not private names): names like `__SomeClass__` or `__a_special_variable__` will be displayed, but names like `__this_is_private` will not.
- [Named tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) are displayed, as is anything that matches the pattern that specifies them: the object's name starts with `_` and the object has a `_fields` attribute (i.e. it has public fields).

There are exceptions to these basic rules; names in the reserved list do *not* get the same treatment:

```
{'__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__credits__',
 '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__initializing__',
 '__loader__', '__module__', '__name__', '__package__',
 '__path__', '__qualname__', '__slots__', '__version__'}
```

Pydoc will automatically build distinct sections for the `__version__`, `__date__`, `__author__`, and `__credits__`. The others are "redundant or internal" (e.g. `__name__` and `__package__` are assigned to their own sections, but Pydoc will also generate those fields automatically whether you set them or not).

All of this can be found by browsing the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/pydoc.py), but there doesn't appear to be any other single place compiling this information — or at least, not one that ranks well in Google.