# ILOG OPL vs. Python

Tags: python, dictionary, mathematical-optimization, ilog, gurobi

I am trying to convert my OPL model to Python using the Gurobi Python API. I wanted to know if there is an equivalent of OPL tuple structure in Python. Best to show an example:

```
tuple tup_Leg
{
    key string Route;
    key string Leg;
    int Curr_Time;
    int Max_Time;
    int Min_Time;
    float Cube;
}

{tup_Leg} set_Leg = DBRead(db,"Exec SPROC ?")(Param);'
```

Route and Leg are sets in my optimization model; Curr_Time, Min_Time, Max_Time and Cube are parameters indexed over the sets Route and Leg.

In OPL, since I am defining Route and Leg as keys, they can be treated as sets and the parameters can be indexed over them. For example, to address Curr_Time, I can do:

```
i.Curr_Time : i in set_Leg
```

I have been trying hard to find an equivalent of this in Python. So far I have the following in Python:

```
import pyodbc 
Param = 123
con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server Native Client     10.0}', server = 'Server', database='db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("execute SPROC @Param =%d" %Param)
result = cur.fetchall()
tup_Leg = dict(((Route, Leg), [Curr_Time, Min_Time, Max_Time, Cube]) for Route, Leg, Curr_Time, Min_Time, Max_Time, Cube in result)
```

I am not sure how can I address Curr_Time or Min_Time? So far I have:

```
for i,j in tup_Leg:
    Curr_Time, Min_Time, Max_Time, Cube = tup_Leg[(i,j)]
```

Is there a better way to do this other than a dict? I am wondering if there are other options which lets me address the table fields the way OPL allows to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[named tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) resemble the opl tuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple
TupLeg = namedtuple('TupLeg', ['route', 'leg', 
                               'curr_time', 'min_time', 'max_time' 'cube'])

tup_legs = dict((result[0], result[1]), TupLeg(*result) for result in cur)
```

A dict is a good data structure for accessing the TupLeg objects by route, leg.  You can access curr_time by

```
tup_legs[(i,j)].curr_time
```

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module contains a lot of algorithms that will allow you to access dictionaries and other collections in ways similar to what you are used to having opl.