# how to extract just the percentage from psutil.phymem_usage() python

Tags: python

I want to get the memory used percentage from `psutil.phymem_usage()`  in python but when I run the function it returns this:

```
usage(total=520048640L, used=503255040L, free=16793600L, percent=81.5)
```

How can I filter it so that only the percent comes through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is a named tuple (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)), and you can just access it like any tuple or as an attribute. Assuming you store the return value in a variable `usage`, you can access the percentage using `usage[3]`(regular tuple access) or `usage.percent`, with the second option being (imho) the most best option. You can also use `psutil.phymem_usage().percent`.