# How to get the percentage of memory usage of a process?

Tags: python, linux, psutil

Using the following code, I can get the memory consumption of a give process in MiB:

```
def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in MB
    import psutil
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20)
    return mem
```

How can I change this to return the percentage of memory consumption?

**Update**: I need to get the current value of `%MEM` column when executing the `top` command in terminal for a specific process.

**Example**: I need this function to return 14.2 for the process id of VirtualBox process.

[image]

Comment: Providing your definition of "percentage of memory consumption" will make it more obvious what you need to do.

Comment: Again, providing the definition of that value will lead you to your answer. What, in simple terms, does it mean? Percentage *of what*?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538263/how-to-extract-just-the-percentage-from-psutil-phymem-usage-python.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Added an example

Comment: @Paul No, that's not what I need. It "_Return the amount of total, used and free physical memory on the system in bytes plus the percentage usage._" I do not need the total value. I need that value for a specific process only.

Comment: Wonder how accurate you need this to be?  I made a loop to continuously `print psutil.phymem_usage().percent` but I get a different number in `top` for the running python process.

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening.  That's not a duplicate then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use [`process.memory_percent()`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/_modules/psutil.html#Process.memory_percent)

This agrees with top. In the test script below, you can change the argument to the range function defining the `consume_memory` array, which is only there to use up memory for testing, and both python output and top output will match:

```
import os
import psutil

def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in percentage like top
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.memory_percent()
    return mem

consume_memory = range(20*1000*1000)

while True:
    print memory_usage_psutil()
```

[image: pythonVstop]

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import sys
import psutil


for id in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(id)
    if ( p.name() == 'firefox' ):
        print("id of firefox process : " + str(id))
        mem = p.memory_percent()
        print ("Memory Perentage for Firefox process is " + str(mem))
```