# Value isn't getting returned in named tuple

Tags: python

When I try to `print Link.votes` I get `<property object at 0x1027b4f18>` returned when I was expecting the value for "votes" (100 in the example below).  Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
from collections import namedtuple

Link = namedtuple('Link', ['id', 'country_id', 'date', 'votes', 'url'])
Link(0, "US", 111105, 100,"http://www.google.com")
print Link.votes
```

Comment: The first google result for "python namedtuple" was the official Python documentation. If you check the namedtuple section, you'll get all the info you need http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new `Link` object. When you write `Link = namedtuple(...)`, you are creating a new class called `Link`. Then, when you write `Link(...)`, this instantiates a `Link` object, whose `.votes` property you can then access.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Link = namedtuple('Link', ['id', 'country_id', 'date', 'votes', 'url'])
mylink = Link(0, "US", 111105, 100, "http://www.google.com")
print mylink.votes
```

Result:

```
100
```