# Converting user input to variable names (python 2.7)

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say Bob enters his name, 'Bob Jones,' into a Tkinter text entry field. Later, I want to be able to access his name like this:

```
BobJones = {
'name':'Bob Jones',
'pet\'s name':'Fido'
}
```

How do I make it so I assign whatever Bob inputs as a new variable without having to manually write it in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: @roippi that doesn't really help

Comment: So you will have variables whose names aren't known when the program is written, and no other way of finding their names once they have been created?  How could this possibly be a good idea?

Comment: You're looking for a dictionary.

Comment: @ScottHunter how do you make "new users" then? I'm pretty new to this :/

Comment: @eli_dink it *does* help.  You're just focused on [how to accomplish your particular solution to the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), rather than solving the actual problem.

Comment: @ooga so I'd want it to be users = {'Bob Jones':{'pet\'s name':'Fido'}} etc.?

Comment: @roippi this was a general problem, nothing like my actual thing I'm working on, which is data visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comments above, I think you'd want something more like this:

```
# Define the user class - what data do we store about users:

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_name, first_pet):
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.first_pet = first_pet

# Now gather the actual list of users

users = []
while someCondition:
    user_name, first_pet = getUserDetails()
    users.append(User(user_name, first_pet))

# Now we can use it

print "The first users name is:"
print users[0].user_name
```

So you're defining the class (think of it as a template) for the Users, then creating new User objects, one for each person, and storing them in the `users` list.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I forgot about classes! thanks a lot, man

Comment: No problem. If you're after sometihng lighter-weight than this (and the data will never be changed 'immutable'), you could use Named Tuples instead of classes, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: No I definitely need to use classes. I'm storing ~50 data points per user.