# How to scale all numbers in a string while keeping the format the same in Python?

Tags: python, string, variables, integer, multiplication

I need a way to multiply all the numbers in a string by another number while keeping the structure and format of the string. Can it be done?

For example:

```
my_var = """Cat, 5, kg 

Dog, 10, kg

Human, 50, kg"""
```

Given this string, I want to be able to multiply 5, 10 and 50 by another number saved in some other variable.

```
multiplier = 2.0/10 # or 0.2
```

So I want to use `multiplier` and `my_var` to create a new string:

```
"""Cat, 1, kg

Dog, 2, kg

Human, 10, kg"""
```

that I would then output to the user.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: An object oriented solution would probably be good here. Deserialize each string into an `Animal` object that has attributes `name`, `mass`, `units`; then multiply each Animal's mass by `2/10`; then re-serialize back into a string.

Comment: Try one line first. Create a string 'Cat, 5, kg', and work out how to [split it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) using the commas, how to convert to an integer using [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), and rejoin using [', '.join(values)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: @Kevin The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for [`namedtuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tryed to implement something? If yes, show us.

Comment: Kevin and Peter Wood- Hi Kevin and Peter, That was what I was thinking but I'm not sure how to re-serialize them back into a string.

Comment: GingerPlusPlus- Hi there, I have tried implementing something, but the problem is my coding is very basic. I have tried just my_var*multiplier and int(my_var) * int(multiplier), hoping that the software would multiply just the numbers and have tried the list technique mentioned above but just knowing how to re-serialize, especially being able to make the program do that by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions with a custom substitution function seem to suit the task well.

We can find all numbers in a string, convert them to integers and perform some arithmetic on them. After that they need to be converted back to strings to replace the former text.

```
import re

text = '''
Cat, 5 kg
Dog, 10 kg
Human, 50 kg
'''.strip()

def divide_numbers(s, n):
    def sub(m):
        return str(int(m.group(0))//n)
    return re.sub('[0-9]+', sub, s)

print(divide_numbers(text, 5))
```

> Cat, 1 kg
>   Dog, 2 kg
>   Human, 10 kg

Do notice that fractional parts are discarded everywhere here. You may want to use `float` instead of `int` and `/` instead of `//` (which is integer division).

Another interesting advantage of regular expressions here is you can make your pattern more advanced to match only some numbers. Here we match only the numbers that are followed by `" kg"`, and I changed to `float` as mentioned

```
def divide_numbers(s, n):
    def sub(m):
        return str(float(m.group(1))/n)
    return re.sub('([0-9]+) kg', sub, s)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked, but is it possible if you could give me explanation on how the code works because I understand you can create your expressions and I understand bits and pieces within this code but is it possible to explain to me how the code works further and what certain words mean within the code, such as m.group(0) and re.sub and "([0-9]+)kg", sub, s)

Comment: @Mohamed http://docs.python.org/library/re.html