# Editing dict values in a method

Tags: python, function, dictionary, immutability, key-value

I have a program where I am keeping the statistics of objects in the game in a dict, like this:

```
Weapon = namedtuple("Weapon", ["owned", "damage", "price", "accuracy"])

weapons = {
    "fists":    Weapon(True, 2, None, 75),
    "knife":    Weapon(False, 4, 50, 95),
    "sword":    Weapon(False, 6, 100, 90),
    "pistol":   Weapon(False, 8, 250, 65),
    "rifle":    Weapon(False, 10, 500, 80),
    "rpg":      Weapon(False, 20, 1000, 100)
}
```

How would I edit The `owned` value from inside of a function?

Comment: Namedtuples are immutable. You could use recordtypes.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: @wrdeman you can use _replace on the namedtuple and re-assign to the dictionary. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

namedtuple is immutable. Why not use classes? Your code will be cleaner, more organized, modular, and easier to reuse.

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, owned, damage, price, accuracy):
        self.owned = owned
        self.damage = damage
        self.price = price
        self.accuracy = accuracy

    def flip_weapon_owned_value(self):
        self.owned = False if self.owned else True
        print "\n", self.owned


weapons = {
    'fists' :  Weapon(True, 2, None, 75),
    'knife' :  Weapon(False, 4, 50, 95),
    'sword' :  Weapon(False, 6, 100, 90),
    'pistol' : Weapon(False, 8, 250, 65),
    'rifle' :   Weapon(False, 10, 500, 80),
    'rpg' :     Weapon(False, 20, 1000, 100)
}

> weapons['fists'].flip_weapon_owned_value()
> False

> weapons['fists'].flip_weapon_owned_value()
> True
```

Comment: `self.owned = !self.owned` is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

A namedtuple allows you to clone it with updated values. See [_replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace). It starts with an underscore so it won't clash with any of your attribute names.

You need to re-assign this updated clone to the dictionary key:

```
weapons = ... # as above

def main():
    do_something(weapons)

def do_something(weapons):
    weapons['fists'] = weapons['fists']._replace(owned=False)
```

Comment: I originally tried this and recieved this error message: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: Why not replace that entry with a new namedtuple instance, rather than try to modify what seems to be an immutable data type?

Comment: Doh! That's exactly what `_replace` does.  My mistake.

Comment: @BlackVegetable No worries, I probably changed the answer when you weren't looking

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of using tuples.

Comment: @mattm it's not marked private, it's so it doesn't clash with your attributes.

Comment: Quote: `In addition to the methods inherited from tuples, named tuples support three additional methods and one attribute. To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore.`