# Get complex enum by property in python 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have complex python `enum` like the following:

```
from enum import Enum

class Properties:
    def __init__(self, name, v, k):
        self.name = name
        self.v = v
        self.k = k


class EnzymeNames(Enum):
    ENZYME_X = Properties("x", 0.2, 50)
    ENZYME_Y = Properties("y", 1.5, 100)

    @property
    def v(self):
        return self.value.v

    @property
    def k(self):
        return self.value.k

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value.name
```

Now currently, I have special function to get an `enum` by its name:

```
def get_enzyme(name) -> EnzymeNames:
    for e in EnzymeNames:
        if str(e) == name:
            return e
```

I was wondering is there any simple/pythonic way to access `enum` just by `EnzymeNames('name')` or similar?

**Edit**:

I think there is little confusion about what I am trying to achieve.  I want to get **EnzymeNames** by property. For example, EnzymeNames('x') should give me **EnzymeNames.ENZYME_X**.

I have already tried following methods:

```
>>EnzymeNames('x')
ValueError: 'x' is not a valid EnzymeNames
>>EnzymeNames('ENZYME_X') 
ValueError: 'ENZYME_X' is not a valid EnzymeNames
>>EnzymeNames['ENZYME_X']
KeyError: 'ENZYME_X'
```

Comment: You can do `EnzymeNames["ENZYME_X"]`

Comment: Also, since `X` and `Y` are meaningless without the `EnzymeNames`, i.e. they cannot be used unbound, I wouldn't have those extra prefixes, instead preferring just `Enzyme.X`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python

Comment: @SelçukCihan : I already tried that. It gives me `ValueError: 'ENZYME_X' is not a valid EnzymeNames`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: If I try to access them without using property function, I get error `AttributeError: 'EnzymeNames' object has no attribute 'X'`

Comment: @VivekKumar: I don't think it is duplicate of question you linked. I want to get enum by property. Not values.

Comment: why wouldn't you use those as the actual names? Otherwise, build a dictionary after the class has been completed, mapping v to the enum

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes. I was doing this with directories before making complex enums. But IMO enum way is much more cleaner. Hence wanted to check if there is any better way.

Comment: Your code works fine for me -- which `Enum` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `enum` are you using?  Testing your code on Pythons 3.6, 3.5, 3.4, 3.3, and 2.7 (using the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) for 2.7 and 3.3) I get this:

```
>>> EnzymeNames['ENZYME_X']
x
```

In other words:  using the built-in `Enum` or the `enum34` backport your code works just fine.

---

A better way to write your enum is to integrate `Properties` into it:

```
from enum import Enum

class Properties:
    def __init__(self, v, k):
        self.v = v
        self.k = k


class EnzymeNames(Properties, Enum):

    X = 0.2, 50
    Y = 1.5, 100

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in use:

```
>>> print(EnzymeNames.X)
X

>>> print(EnzymeNames.X.name)
X

>>> print(EnzymeNames.X.v)
0.2

>>> print(EnzymeNames.X.k)
50

>>> print(EnzymeNames['X'])
X
```

---

Some general tips for writing `enums`:

- Keep the name singular;  `EnzymeName` instead of `EnzymeNames`
- Don't repeat the enum name in the enum member: `X` instead of `ENZYME_X`
- If you're doing fancy stuff with `Enum`, consider using the [`Advanced Enum library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) (written by the same author as `Enum` and `enum34`)

Using `aenum`, your code might look like:

```
from aenum import Enum

class EnzymeName(Enum, init='v k'):

    X = 0.2, 50
    Y = 1.5, 100

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slight reorganization of your code to use `namedtuples`.  They are  lightweight, easy to create objects that like `enums`, are immutable.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970722/7311767) for a better explanation than I could put together on what they are.

Here is your code with two methods added to retrieve an instance via the `Properties` attribute values.

**Code:**

```
from enum import Enum
import collections
import math

Properties = collections.namedtuple('Properties', 'v k')

class EnzymeNames(Enum):
    x = Properties(0.2, 50)
    y = Properties(1.5, 100)

    @property
    def v(self):
        return self.value.v

    @property
    def k(self):
        return self.value.k

    @classmethod
    def from_v(cls, v):
        for en in cls:
            if math.isclose(en.v, v):
                return en

    @classmethod
    def from_k(cls, k):
        for en in cls:
            if math.isclose(en.k, k):
                return en
```

**Test Code:**

```
an_enzyme = EnzymeNames.from_k(100)
print(an_enzyme)
print('name:', an_enzyme.name)
print('k:', an_enzyme.k)
print('v:', an_enzyme.v)
```

**Output:**

```
EnzymeNames.y
name: y
k: 100
v: 1.5
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain namedtupple part little bit ?