# When should I use and when should I avoid namedtuple in Python?

Tags: python, namedtuple

During my online class one of my python tutors told me that `namedtuple` can cause more harm than good.

I am confused why. Can someone please specify when to use `namedtuple` and when not to?

Comment: It can make you become too great a programmer and put him out of a job

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "named tuples" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)

Comment: It adds great readibility to your code, and that's what python is for. Objectively, one could argue that `namedtuple` would be more memory consuming than a simple `tuple`. But if we wanted everything to be optimal to the max, we would all be programming websites in Assembly. But we are not because we have powerful machines nowadays. It **can cause** more harm than good **if-and-only-if** you absolutely need your program to be fast and optimized : in which case, you might not choose python at all. You can see a namedtuple as an immutable dict.

Comment: BY THE WAY, I shall encourage you to **ask** your teacher the question yourself next time. Good students are students that are not afraid to ask things they did not understand. You didn't understand why `namedtuple can cause more harm than good` ? Ask him to provide details. What if he can't ? He might be just as wrong as a student that will not provide details about his answer in his test.

Comment: @IMCoins I thought I am stupid to have such question. :) As  no one asked

Comment: “The only stupid question is the question that is never asked.” :)

Comment: I think the answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/349742) is better than the ones posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problem's what I can see is

You can't specify default arguments values for namedtuple classes.This makes them unwieldy when your data may have many optional properties .

The attribute values of namedtuple instances are still accessible using numerical indexes and iteration .Especially in externalised API's , this can lead to unintentional usage that makes it harder to move to real class later.If you are not in control of all of the usage of namedtuple instances , its' better define your own class

and for when to use it please do see the comment by IMCoins

Answer (score 4):

The classic example of namedtuple is something like this...

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(x=1, y=2)
>>> p.x
1
p.y
2
```

The thing I think most people find attractive at first is the ability to make a class so easily and be able to instanciate with keyword args `Point(x=1, y=2)` and do dotted access like `p.x` and `p.y`.

However, there are a lot of things that are easily overlooked and is rather inflexible. Unexpected things can happen for subclasses, too. Unless namedtuple really hits your use-case, you're better off using `SimpleNamespace` if you just want dotted-name lookups and a nice repr.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Point(SimpleNameSpace):
    def __init__(self, x, y=0):
        # simple wrapper to accept arguments positionally or as keywords with defaults
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am trying to use upvote .don't know why it is not working