# Trying to translate an old pascal script to python: problems with pascal "record"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascal

i'm currently tasked with translating an old pascal script to python. Problem is, i don't have any of experience with pascal... Until now, all went fine (most of the script is pretty self-explanatory), but now i encountered a small snippet of code which i just can't figure out:

```
# some other code here...

type MeasurementPoint = record
                         lambda : double;
                         value : double;
                        end;

# some more code...

procedure foo(MyFileName: string, somemoreargs):
var  somevars: integer; 
     somemorevars: double;
     temp: MeasurementPoint; 

# even more code...

  i:= 0;
  Assign(MyInFile,MyFileName);
  Reset(MyInFile);
  repeat
    Inc(i);
    SetLength(Reflexion, i);
    readln(MyInFile, temp.lambda, temp.value);
    Reflexion[i-1]:=temp;
  until EoF(MyInFile);
  Close(MyInFile);
```

I just cant't wrap my head around what this part of code is supposed to do... 
I understand so much that the full file `MyInFile` is being read line after line, and that each line contains two values, namely `'lambda'` and `'value'`, which are extracted as doubles.

According to the pascal wiki, `record` is a container able to hold objects of different types and logically group them together (could this be compared to a dictionary in python?). If i understand `SetLength` correctly, it is used to definde the length of an array, which makes sense here. `i` is increased every time a line is read, so the length of `temp` is increased to fit the number of `lambda` and `value` pairs already extracted from the file (please correct me if my assumptions are wrong!). But i don't understand what the rest of the code is supposed to do, especially `Reflexion[i-1]:=temp`. Is `Reflexion` an object of the type `MeasurementPoint` with length i-1? Or what does that part mean? Why are `lambda` and `value` extracted as `temp.lambda` and `temp.value`? does this automatically pair them together in a record...?

If anyone could help me by explaining this, i would highly appreciate it. And, of course, if you happen to have any idea how this could be translated into python 3.x, it would be even better ;-)

Comment: A class or even a named tuple could replace the record.

Comment: yea, the namedtuple was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal's `record` is like Python's [`namedtuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python). One record (namedtuple) is read field by field (hence `temp.lambda`, `temp.value`) in `readLn` function.

`Reflexion[i-1]:=temp` looks like an array (Python's `list`) of records. Since arrays have  a constant length (declared at initialization; `n-1`) the new records are stored in the consecutive slots.

I hope this answers your questions about what the Pascal code does...

Comment: It definitely gave me some more insight, thank you! And i just learned about named tuples through you... so i'm even more thankful.