# How to convert class objects to named tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, namespaces, namedtuple

I really want to use namedtuples instead of class objects

```
class objects 

class ZoneFileObject(object):
    def __init__(
            self,
            descriptor='',
            name='',
            filehandle='',
    ):
        self.descriptor = descriptor
        self.name = name
        self.filehandle = filehandle
```

optimized namedtuple in single line

Comment: Do you want help creating a named tuple with these three things in?

Comment: Have you tried using namedtuple? What problem did you have with it?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970722/5549711)

Answer (score 2):

Import the `namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

Then create one:

```
ZoneFileObject = namedtuple('ZoneFileObject', ['descriptor', 'name', 'filehandle'])
zfo = ZoneFileObject('Happy', 'Sad', 'file')
```

and use it:

```
>>> zfo.descriptor
'Happy'
```