# Can you return an object from a function without creating a class?

Tags: python

Coming from other scripting languages like AutoHotkey and PowerShell, it seems verbose to have to declare a class in order to return an object from a function. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this in Python?

```
def structuring_element():
    return {kind: 'flat'; structure: []}

tool = structuring_element()
print(tool.kind)
# 'flat'
print(tool.structure)
# []
```

Looks like the simplest way is to declare a class and create the structuring element in the `__init__` statement like so:

```
class structuring_element(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.kind = 'flat'
        self.structure = []
```

Currently I'm using multiple outputs but it doesn't feel as elegant as being able to keep them in an object together:

```
def structuring_element():
    return 'flat', []

kind, structure = structuring_element()
```

Comment: Everything in Python is an object.  What's wrong with the dictionary object you return in your first example?

Comment: @Samwise `tool.kind` won't work, it has to be `tool['kind']`

Comment: Don't name your variable the same as the function. You won't be able to call the function again.

Comment: It should be a comma not a semicolon in the return statement.

Comment: I think what you want is a [named tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)

Comment: "Currently I'm using multiple outputs": no, you are returning a *tuple* that contains your elements. As such, you can keep them together as a tuple. And the namedtuple functions similarly, but with easier access to the individual elements.

Comment: A dict works but I'm not sure why I can't return an object just the same.

```
def tool():
    return {'kind': 'flat', 'structure': []}
```

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to Python. I thought a tuple was contained in parethesis. What's the difference between return x, y and return (x, y)?

Comment: @Barmar that's exactly what I'm looking for!
`return namedtuple('nt', 'kind structure')(kind, structure)`