# Python list.pop Specific Element, eg List.pop(0)(0)

Tags: python, list, discord.py

I want to make a Discord Bot and I am stuck at one thing: I have a music queue, and i only want to delete the first song from it, but the queue is 2 rows deep.

```
[['url': '...', 'title': '...']['url2': '...','title2': '...']]
```

I only want to pop the first part, so in the end its

```
[['url2': '...','title2': '...']]
```

Ive searched through many Forums but didnt find an answer.
Can anyone please help?? Thanks!

Comment: Just a tip: Consider storing your song records in something like a `class` or [`NamedTuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573457/3282436), rather than a `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
>>> my_list.pop(0)
['a', 'b']
>>> my_list
[['c', 'd']]
>>>
```