# Print named tuple value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, namedtuple

A function is returning me the below list of named tuples:

```
[popenfile(path='/home/giampaolo/monit.py', fd=3, position=0, mode='r', flags=32768), popenfile(path='/var/log/monit.log', fd=4, position=235542, mode='a', flags=33793)]
```

I want to print the value of 'path' in the tuple. How to do this? Please help dear community.

I tried to follow online articles but no solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "named tuples" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)

Comment: These examples show how to add values in tuple and then access that. But, I want to access & print values of named tuples that I found from another function.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, these examples have already shown you how to access values.

Comment: I can't understand how to access each popenfile tuple and its value using for loop.

Comment: So you should ask or search how to use the for loop, a simple example: `for tpl in your_list: print(tpl.path)`

Comment: Thanks. But this is giving the below error:
NameError: name 'popenfile' is not defined

Comment: You need to define the form of the namedtuple. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear see below code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

popenfile = namedtuple('popenfile', 'path fd position mode flags')

tuple_list = [popenfile(path='/home/giampaolo/monit.py', fd=3, position=0, mode='r', flags=32768), popenfile(path='/var/log/monit.log', fd=4, position=235542, mode='a', flags=33793)]

for ntup in tuple_list:
    print(ntup.path)
```

which prints

```
/home/giampaolo/monit.py
/var/log/monit.log
```