# Give variables 2 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, poker

```
import random, time

from enum import Enum

class CardSuits(Enum):
    Hearts = "Hearts"
    Diamonds = "Diamonds"
    Clubs = "Clubs"
    Spades = "Spades"

class CardValues(Enum):
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = "J"
    Queen = "Q"
    King = "K"
    Ace = "A"


class Card:

    _symbols = {"Hearts": "♥️", "Diamonds": "♦️", "Clubs": "♣️", "Spades": "♠"}

    def __init__(self, suit: CardSuits, value: CardValues) -> None:
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name}{self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name}{self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"


def start():
    play = input("You wanna play? ")
    if play.lower() in ("yes", "sure", "yeah"):
        unique_cards = set()
        while len(unique_cards) < 5:
            unique_cards.add(Card(random.choice(list(CardValues)), random.choice(list(CardSuits))))
        cards = list(unique_cards)
        print("Your cards are:", ", ", cards)
        time.sleep(4)
```

To use it you create individual cards via:

```
card = Card(CardSuits.Clubs, CardValues.Ace)
```

With this you mean that I have to create every single card of the deck or is it like a sample where all other cards will get the "creation way"?
It keeps telling me there's an error there: {self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"

And also, up to this point is all right? I modified a little bit the first part, when it will be ok, I'll modify the rest fo the code based on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "named tuples" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)

Comment: With a dictionary? `suits = {"hearts": "♥️", "diamonds": "♦️", "clubs": "♣️", "spades": "♠"}`

Comment: no, already tried, gives error. Then i'll read about named tuples

Comment: When you add cards to unique_card, you mixed up CardValues and CardSuits as suits have to come first (as defined in the `__init__`() ). Otherwise this looks good to me. 
And to create a list of all cards in the deck you can use list comprehension: `all_cards =[Card(suit, value) for suit in CardSuits for value in CardValues]`. To shuffle it you can use `shuffle()` from the `random` library.

Comment: @Oskar  Gosh I'm stupid... I didn't saw that littlw detail, thank you. Now I'm having a little problem with changing cards, but I'll try almost a little bit alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently handling your cards simply as strings. As each card has two separate properties (value and suit) I propose you define a `Card` class. This allows you to easily retrieve and change the value and suit of a class and also define a way on how to print a card.

One possible example would be something like

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class CardSuits(Enum):
    Clubs = auto() # 1
    Spades = auto() # 2
    Hearts = auto() # 3
    Diamonds = auto() # 4

class CardValues(Enum):
    Ace = auto() # 1
    Deuce = auto() # 2
    Three = auto() # 3
    Four = auto() # 4
    Five = auto() # 5
    Six = auto() # 6
    Seven = auto() # 7
    Eight = auto() # 8
    Nine = auto() # 9
    Ten = auto() # 10
    Jack = auto() # 11
    Queen = auto() # 12
    King = auto() # 13

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit: CardSuits, value: CardValues) -> None:
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name} of {self.suit.name}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name} of {self.suit.name}"
```

You do not need to define the two Enum-classes but it really helps when you often deal with these properties in your card game. The code above is from a [blackjack game I wrote for myself](https://github.com/OskarHofmann/Blackjack/tree/main), if you are interested in further references on how to use this class.

To use it you create individual cards via:

```py
card = Card(CardSuits.Clubs, CardValues.Ace)
```

And you can redefine the `__str__` (and `__repr__`) function if you prefer to use symbols for printing to the console, e.g.:

```py
class Card:

    _symbols = {"Hearts": "♥️", "Diamonds": "♦️", "Clubs": "♣️", "Spades": "♠"}

    def __init__(self, suit: CardSuits, value: CardValues) -> None:
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name} of {self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.name} of {self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"
```

Comment: I tried and it gives me an error on _symbols dict

Comment: And one question: what is .name ?

Comment: Sorry there was missing a self in front of _symbols. I edited my solution. And ".name" uses the name of an Enum as string. So for example "Clubs".

Comment: To use it you must create a card via e.g. 
card = Card(suit = CardSuits.Clubs, value = CardValues.Six)

Comment: I read today about enum and i've got what u said about .name, it was actually really simple.  But I've not understand yet how i can use these classes (str method specifically) in my code, or better said, how i can implement and modify my code with them, because (even If I get that this way to create and assign values to cards is basically the same thing that I've done, only in a better and experienced way) this is actually the first time I code with this "method". So if you coould give me an hint of the things to do (not a solution, i want to code it from myself) i would appreciate that

Comment: The __str__ method is called when you try to print an object. So with the cards you do not have to manually write an f-string everytime you want to print out a card in a nice format to the user. You can just define it once and then call print() on you Card object. The Card objects help you to easier set, retrieve and print cards and you do not have to store strings. It also allows you to print out symbols but do not have to type them when changing a card.
Can you specify what your current problem is with your code?

Comment: I've replied to you as an answer, otherwise it would be difficult to explain the problem without the modified code

Comment: modified the code at the beginning and asked 2 little question, because someone had to delete my answer below.